# How to make graphics (Shape, animation) in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, graphics

How to make a circle with text inside ?? then move it from one location to another, and then access it later (to delete it).

I want to make something like [this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html)

Comment: You can create a `Circle` class containing some properties and a `Draw` method which accepts a `Graphics` object and draw the circle on graphics object. Then you can stole your circles in a data structure which you need and draw them on a surface. Moving objects is just changing circle properties and then invalidating drawing surface and so on. Take a look at this example: [how can i treat the circle as a control after drawing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345828/how-can-i-treat-the-circle-as-a-control-after-drawing-it)

Comment: Or use a Chart with EllipseAnnotations. But plan ahead for the full scope of what you want to do!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really very broad and you got a few nice links you should study to learn all about `GDI+` drawing.

But if taken literally there is a slightly exotic alternative which puts the burdon of most chores onto the `Chart` control from `DataVisualization.Charting`.

You can create `EllipseAnnotations` and add them to a `Chart` control.

Disable the `Axes` and clear the `Legends` and then use code like this to add a moveable circle wit thext inside:

```
EllipseAnnotation ea = new EllipseAnnotation();
ea.X = 11;  // put at..
ea.Y = 11;  // 11% of the chart's area
ea.AllowMoving = true;
ea.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
ea.Text = (chart1.Annotations.Count + 1) + "";
chart1.Annotations.Add(ea);
```

[image]

Note that there are quite a few annotation types available. which allow you to add `Rectangles`, `Images`, `Polygons`, `Lines` and pure `Text`.

And another pro is that **saving or loading** the graphics takes only one line each, as you can **serialize** a `Chart` out of the box!
 :-)

Comment: Nice illustration @Taw and also you are right it needs the basic understanding first.

Answer (score 0):

GraphX for .NET is an advanced open-source graph layout and visualization library that supports different layout algorithms and provides many means for visual customizations It is capable of rendering large amount of vertices

https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX

Answer (score -1):

To draw shapes follow [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488183.aspx).Also you need a complete tut,you can follow [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx)

Some insight is here:

> To draw a simple shape at design time Drag the `OvalShape` or
>   `RectangleShape` control from the Visual Basic PowerPacks tab (to
>   install, see Visual Basic Power Packs Controls)in the Toolbox to a
>   form or container control.
>
> Drag the sizing and move handles to size and position the shape. You
>   can also size and position the shape by changing the Size and Position
>   properties in the Properties window To create a rectangle with rounded
>   corners, select the CornerRadius property in the Properties window
>   and set it to a value that is greater than 0. In the Properties
>   window, optionally set additional properties to change the appearance
>   of the shape.
>
> To draw a simple shape at run time On the Project
>   menu, click Add Reference. In the Add Reference dialog box, select
>   `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS`, and then click OK. In the Code
>   Editor, add an Imports or using statement at the top of the module:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks; Add the following code in an Event procedure:
>
> ShapeContainer canvas = new ShapeContainer();
> // To draw an oval, substitute 
> // OvalShape for RectangleShape.
> RectangleShape theShape = new RectangleShape();
> // Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
> canvas.Parent = this;
> // Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the Shape.
> theShape.Parent = canvas;
> // Set the size of the shape.
> theShape.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 300);
> // Set the location of the shape.
> theShape.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
> // To draw a rounded rectangle, add the following code:
> theShape.CornerRadius = 12;
> ```
>
> Customizing Shapes When you use the default settings, the OvalShape and RectangleShape controls are
>   displayed with a solid black border that is one pixel wide and a
>   transparent background. You can change the width, style, and color of
>   the border by setting properties. Additional properties enable you to
>   change the background of a shape to a solid color, a pattern, a
>   gradient fill, or an image. Before you change the background of a
>   shape, you should know how several of the properties interact. The
>   `BackColor` property setting has no effect unless the `BackStyle` property
>   is set to Opaque. If the `FillStyle` property is set to Solid, the
>   `FillColor` overrides the `BackColor`. If the `FillStyle` property is set to
>   a pattern value such as Horizontal or Vertical, the pattern will be
>   displayed in the `FillColor`. The background will be displayed in the
>   `BackColor`, provided that the `BackStyle` property is set to Opaque. In
>   order to display a gradient fill, the `FillStyle` property must be set
>   to Solid and the `FillGradientStyle` property must be set to a value
>   other than None. Setting the `BackgroundImage` property to an image
>   overrides all other background settings.

This SO link I found is also nice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981840/how-to-draw-and-move-shapes-using-mouse-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please refrain from link-only answers. Links die. If you can't include the essence of the links put them into comments instead!

Comment: ok will do @TaW.The question is broad in its essense and needs thorough knowledge.

Comment: *"The question is broad in its essense"* Then you should **[flag to close the question as off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)** instead of answering it. You can do so by clicking on the "flag" link under the question. Thanks.