# Draw a moving rectangle on windows form

Tags: c#, forms

how do i draw a moving rectangle in windows form in pure c#? i can't find anything anywhere surprisingly, it's always a tutorial by using visual studio. I'm looking for ways to do it in pure c# without any ide. Here is what i tried so far.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace form
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Form myform = new Form();

             while (myform.Created)
             {

             }

             Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. It doesn’t make the code “impure C#” if you write code in a specific editor

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Visual studio let's you pick a project type and one of them is windows form application, if you select that it's no longer pure c# because it already adds extra functions to make things easier. Most tutorials I found are using visual studio and it's not what i want.

Comment: @JamesPenner If you follow that logic `using System.Drawing;` is not "pure" either.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRpYDTegGyo like in this video, c# doesnt even have a InitializeComponent() function and in visual studio you dont even have to instantiate the form class to make a window. it's definitely not pure c#. I probably worded things badly, what I meant is not using any extra code/functions/libraries from an IDE.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen I probably worded things badly, what I meant is not to use any IDE. just a notepad, a .cs file and a c# compiler

Comment: @JamesPenner there you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: @gsharp that's not what i meant, I'm looking for the code to draw and move the rectangle, not how to compile it.

Comment: @JamesPenner did you google it? it's full of examples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981840/how-to-draw-and-move-shapes-using-mouse-in-c-sharp

Comment: @gsharp it's not what I want, the link you shown is using an ide, im looking for the code without any ide

Comment: @JamesPenner yeah but not that much the code that is generated in InizializeComponent() is just minimal, you can adapt that code in no time to your needs. I really don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times when building things out "by hand" rather than relying on templates/autogeneration are useful to get to know a technology. I don't, personally, believe that is the case here, but I'll try to provide some guidance anyway.

The first thing to know is that you need to run a message loop. I'd strongly recommend using the standard .NET implementation of this (certainly if you want to use other classes within the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace) and that's [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netframework-4.8):

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread.

But we got a little ahead of ourselves there. We also should be running that from an STA Thread. We get one thread when our application starts running and that calls into `Main`. But you can't change the apartment state of a thread after it's started running. So you best add the [STAThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to your `Main` method so the runtime knows to run it on an STA thread instead<sup>1</sup>.

Once you do both of those things (passing your `myForm` to `Application.Run`) you'll have a form shown on screen. You'll want to run other code as well, such as to add controls to your form (`myform` will be completely empty) or to take over drawing, and you'll want to do those from methods that the framework calls on the Form<sup>2</sup>.

For custom drawing, I'd suggest starting at looking at overriding [`OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onpaint?view=netframework-4.8)

You'll also want to start telling the compiler that your target is `winexe` rather than `exe` so that you don't have a console window attached. You'll also have to stop using `Console` methods.

---

<sup>1</sup>By default, the runtime will make your first thread an MTA thread instead.

<sup>2</sup>Most obviously, because the thread you had is now running the message loop and calling into those methods; the call to `Application.Run` doesn't return until the form closes; and you can't (easily) use multiple threads with UI components.